# Can someone explain to me what "wget -O - -q icanhazip.com" mean?

Tags: linux, centos, wget

I've used this command to find the IP of the server. Can someone explain what the command means? I want to learn.

So far I know:
"wget" is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web [http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm]

"-O" Writes the documents to File

"-q" quiet (no output)

But why use that "-" in between?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "-O -" means it will write the output to standard output (your console).   Generally, you can use "-" as a file with many command line tools to send their output to stdout.

Comment: Just to be clear stdout is the command line right?

Comment: No, `stdout` is the normal output pathway which, when you launch a program from the shell, is connected to your terminal/console.

Comment: STDOUT is a file descriptor that is used by process to send normal messages to the terminal. It can be redirected with a pipe "|" to be the STDIN for another command.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [man page for `wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget), which explains the `-O` option and the meaning of the hyphen.

> -O file
>
> --output-document=file
>
> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file. **If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output**, disabling link conversion. (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)